# How can I access the target of a runAction with a callback function?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have the following code:

```
    id enterRight = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1.5f position:ccp(-600, 0)];
    id exitLeft = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1.5f position:ccp(-600, 0)];
    id reset = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0 position:ccp(1200, 0)];
    id actionCallFunc = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(cleanPatterns)];

    id seq1 = [CCSequence actions: [[exitLeft copy] autorelease],
    [[actionCallFunc copy] autorelease], [[reset copy] autorelease],
    [[enterRight copy] autorelease],  nil];


    [sprite runAction: [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[seq1 copy]]];
```

I want my callback function, cleanPatterns, to be able to reference the object 'sprite'.

Is there some method by which the method can discover which object the runAction is happening to?

Comment: with CCCallFuncO you can pass an object as a parameter to cleanPatterns

Comment: @Ultrakorne Could you elaborate further, perhaps with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ultrakorne mentioned in his comment, you can access the target object directly in your callback if you define it as follows:

```
-(void) cleanPatterns:(id)sender 
{
    // sender is your target object
    CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)sender;

    // Then do something to your sprite...
}
```

Back at where you defined your *actionCallFunc*, remember to append a colon behind cleanPatterns since your callback method now takes one argument:

```
id actionCallFunc = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(cleanPatterns:)];
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully, but I was getting bad access errors until I changed CCCallFunc to CCCallFuncN. I've suggested an edit to incorporate that.

Comment: oh yeah, my apologies.. thanks for catching that, makes a big difference!